# Find closest selector using JQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

For the below HTML and JQuery, the first two `closest()` calls find the expected element, but the third one does not find the header element. Is there a way to find it using jquery?

```
<div class="top">
  <div class="header"></div>
  <div class="body>
    <a href="#" class="js-clickable">clickable</a>
  </div>
</div>

$('.js-clickable').on('click', function (data) {

  var clickable = $(data.toElement);

  var top= clickable.closest('.top');
  var body= clickable.closest('.body');
  var header = clickable.closest('.header');

});
```

Comment: `div.header` is not a parent of `a.js-clickable`.

Comment: It is because header is not a an ancestor.

Comment: Given the wide range of [traversal functions](https://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/), I'm pretty sure there is a way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the proper selector for your use case:

```
var header = clickable.closest("*:has(.header)").find(".header");
```

Answer (score 1):

Because header is not an ancestor you can go a couple of ways.

```
var header = clickable.closest('.body').prev('.header');
```

You could also go to the clickable's grandparent and come back down.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
var header = button.closest('.header');
```

To:

```
var header = button.closest('.top').find('.header');
```

Learn more here: https://api.jquery.com/closest/

Comment: It doesn't need to be in the `.top`.

Answer (score 0):

This would work:

```
var header = clickable.closest('.body').prev('.header');
```